# ServiceStack and HttpError

Tags: servicestack

In ServiceStack is there an implementation of HttpError?

I can find the interface definition:

```
namespace ServiceStack.ServiceHost
{
    public interface IHttpError : IHttpResult, IHasOptions
    {
        string ErrorCode { get; }
        string Message { get; }
    }
}
```

But am I missing a using directive, because I get this compiler error:

The type or namespace name 'HttpError' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `HttpError` class is in the `ServiceStack.Common.Web` namespace ([ServiceStack.Common](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common/) assembly/NuGet package) in the [current (version 3) release](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v3/src/ServiceStack.Common/Web/HttpError.cs) of ServiceStack.

In under-development [version 4](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/HttpError.cs), looks like it was moved to the root `ServiceStack` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out how to search namespaces, in VS2012 anyway... Select the class and type Shift-Alt-F10... this causes a little dropdown box to appear... click on it and you will see the namespaces that have matching class names!